# Unity Saving Raw image

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, save

I'm trying to save a texture from the Raw Image, however when I save the saved ima

Comment: Your issue may be solved because you are running this on the Editor. When you start building it, you realize that this code will fail. You can't write save data to `Application.streamingAssetsPath` during run-time. You can can only read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 texture.SetPixels(texture.GetPixels());
```

You are copying the pixels from *texture* into *texture*. Are you trying to copy the pixels from *frame* into *texture*?

```
    Texture2D frameTexture = (Texture2D) frame.mainTexture;
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(frameTexture.width, frameTexture.height);

    texture.SetPixels(frameTexture.GetPixels());
    texture.Apply();
```

Comment: Eh!!! That was the issue! Thank you !